# Why won't Rhythmbox work?

Tags: 12.04, rhythmbox, plugins, lts, mp3

I'm using **Ubuntu 12.04 LTS** and found out that **Rhythmbox** won't work-- it keeps saying that it requires plugins but everytime I lookup mp3 plugins it appears that the ones that are all needed are already installed-- what do I do fr. here?  Help!!!

P.S.:  I'm a newbie so any handholding would be deeply appreciated.  :)

Comment: Emily, when you say it 'won't work' what do you mean? **No** songs play, **some** songs play, Rhythmbox fails to even start,etc... Please edit both the title and the body of your question so we can better help you. It's probably something simple but your question needs more detail first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed ubuntu-restricted-extras?
You can get them from here https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-restricted-extras/